# How to fix this bug : "android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package"

Tags: android, android-notifications

The crash info is :

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package com.xx.xx:
Couldn't create icon: StatusBarIcon(pkg=com.xx.xx user=0 id=0x7f02035c level=0      visible=true num=0 )  
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1372)  
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)  
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5139)  
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)  
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)  
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)  
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I think the problem is can not find the drawable resource by the resId. what's your opinion?

Comment: Please, post the code where this error is happening

Comment: the crash info send by user, the count of the notification used by this project is more than ten. i cant figure out which one crashed.

Comment: which process crashed?

Comment: Try my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317659/how-to-fix-android-app-remoteserviceexception-bad-notification-posted-from-pac/45814999#45814999

Answer (score 15):

I was facing the same problem. I noticed I was using Vector Drawable for small icon and this error occurred only on pre-lollipop devices. Using PNG resource for pre-lollipop devices fixed the issue.

Comment: Fixed my issue!

Comment: Using a PNG does not always fix the issue, I still get sometimes this error on Android 5.1 only. More explanations here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26024747/2206688

Answer (score 9):

### TL;DR

When using Firebases ability to set notification, use a PNG instead of a vector by setting `default_notification_icon` in AndroidManifest.xml

### Long description

We had the problem when receiving push notifications on a LG G2 with Android 4.4.2
Fabric (and catlog) showed the following stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package de.xxx.xxx: Couldn't create icon: StatusBarIcon(pkg=de.xxx.xxx=0 id=0x7f0200a6 level=0 visible=true num=0 )
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1367)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Notice, there is no class in stack trace matching our package. Also, `onMessageReceived` was called (checked not only with debug break point but also `Log.e(TAG, "...")`).
This means, that it's not us setting the notification, it is Firebase SDK.

Since there is no code involved, I figured (after painful hours of head banging) error must be in AndroidManifest.xml.
We are setting another notification icon with the following snippet:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />
```

Here, `@drawable/ic_notification` was a vector drawable (SVG). I changed it to a PNG and the crash was gone.

Comment: Thank you for helping

Answer (score 3):

I have seen the "Couldn't create icon: StatusBarIcon" error before and it happens from using an invalid resource id with setSmallIcon on a NotificationCompat.Builder instance. Also if you do not set a small icon at all then your notification will not display. You can use getApplicationInfo().icon as a quick fallback if your code is trying to get the resource id at runtime.