# How to fix: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package *: Couldn't create icon: StatusBarIcon

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-resources, android-drawable

I'm seeing the following exception in crash logs:

```java
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package com.my.package: Couldn't create icon: StatusBarIcon(pkg=com.my.package user=0 id=0x7f02015d level=0 visible=true num=0 )
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1456)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm posting my Notification from an IntentService from a PendingIntent set via the AlarmManager using the following method.  All values passed in here are from the bundle extras in the PendingIntent / IntentService.

```java
/**
 * Notification 
 *
 * @param c
 * @param intent
 * @param notificationId
 * @param title
 * @param message
 * @param largeIcon
 * @param smallIcon
 */
public static void showNotification(Context c, Intent intent,
        int notificationId, String title, String message, int largeIcon,
        int smallIcon) {
    PendingIntent detailsIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(c,
            notificationId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // BUILD
    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            c);
    // TITLE
    mNotifyBuilder.setContentTitle(title).setContentText(message);

    // ICONS
    mNotifyBuilder.setSmallIcon(smallIcon);
    if (Util.isAndroidOSAtLeast(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)) {
        Bitmap large_icon_bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) c.getResources()
                .getDrawable(largeIcon)).getBitmap();
        mNotifyBuilder.setLargeIcon(large_icon_bmp);
    }

    mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(detailsIntent);
    mNotifyBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] { 500, 1500 });
    mNotifyBuilder.setTicker(message);
    mNotifyBuilder.setContentText(message);

    // NOTIFY
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) c
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(notificationId, mNotifyBuilder.build());
}
```

From what I've seen of other answers - the exception I'm seeing happens when `setSmallIcon()` is not called properly.

I've checked and double checked that the Resource IDs being passed are all correct.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same error (crash reports from a live app). I can't reproduce it on my device. I'm currently thinking it's because people modified the .apk

Comment: Guys, in which way can I solve this problem. I use pngs, but very rarely app crashes

Answer (score 114, accepted):

What was happening was, I was including the integer reference to the icon in the PendingIntent bundle, and that integer was later being referenced while being posted to the NotificationManager.

In between getting the integer reference and the pending intent going off, the app was updated and all of the drawable references changed.  The integer that used to reference the correct drawable now referenced either the incorrect drawable or none at all (none at all - causing this crash)

Comment: Bizarre. In other words, this isn't fixable is it? I'm seeing the same crashes in my app.

Comment: It does not seem fixable.  I will, in the future, have to devise a different way to go about posting notifications with images in the future....

Comment: What if we try to set the textSize of the remote view as ret.setInt(id, "setTextSize", 20); It also crashes. I know we also have to provide the units, but how do I do that with such method signature. Any pointer??

Comment: I have the same problem. Currently researching the possibility of using a custom view utilizing the RemoteViews.ActionException in order to handle the exception raised in this scenario. I'll report if I find a way to make it work.
Another approach is to get the drawables used in the notification to get the same ID under R.drawable when compiling so that the icon get the same ID in subsequent builds (but I still haven't figured out how to do it and wether it's even possible).

Comment: Could it be possible to clear the notification and everything related when the app is killed to be updated? (Assuming that would make the app avoid the issue)

Comment: In case you want to reference R.drawable.my_image, it's safer to save it to bundle as a string( `bundle.putString("img", "my_image")`and then convert when needed to actual @DrawableRes integer as follows: `ctx.resources.getIdentifier(bundle.getString("img"), "drawable", ctx.packageName)`

Comment: Please can you show us what you were doing in code? Not sure what you mean by 'integer reference' - aren't they all integer references?

Comment: I have the same issue but its unknown crash I dont know how to resolved this issue any one please guide me ....

Comment: I have this crash and the explanation almost makes sense except for Fabric claims the same user has crashed 10 times, wouldn't this type of crash only happen once and be very rare and would probably never affect the same user again just because of what all has to align for it to happen?

Comment: there is not a true fix for this, but I was able to workaround this by recreating the notification before I notified the NotificationManager (i know this isn't an option for everyone, but for me it is). that way when you set the icon, you're setting it with the current resource id. Looks like from the NotificationCompat.Builder docs that Google is planning to add a constructor to easily clone a Notification in the future so you won't have to fully reassemble a new Notification.

Comment: @M. Smith how you recreate the notification  , what you mean by this in code ?

Answer (score 57):

Using `VectorXml` inside your notification has been known to cause this issue. Use png's

Comment: Only PNGs were being used.

Comment: In my case, I had vector in `drawable` folder and png's in `drawable-hdpi`, `xhdpi`, etc. But there was no png for `drawable-mdpi`, and it crashed on MDPI device on posting a notification.

Answer (score 38):

> Don't use SVG on Kitkat!

I had the same issue every time when I wanted to show a notification on Kitkat. What caused the problem for me is that I have defined every icon in xml (from svg), the small icon and the action icon also. After I have replaced them with png-s the problem solved at my side.

Comment: I can confirm. Vector drawables in notifications cause RemoteServiceException on KitKat.

Comment: In the case of KitKat, the problem was resolved when I replaced the XML with PNG in: new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.my_icon)

Comment: This worked for me. I was running API 19 and used a SVG file for notification icon and was giving me this error, until I switched it to a small png icon

Answer (score 12):

My problem was that the icon I was using on

```
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_push_notif)
```

wasn't generated accordingly. According to the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar):

> As described in Providing Density-Specific Icon Sets and Supporting
>   Multiple Screens, you should create separate icons for all generalized
>   screen densities, including low-, medium-, high-, and
>   extra-high-density screens. This ensures that your icons will display
>   properly across the range of devices on which your application can be
>   installed.

So the best way to fullfill the above, I used ***Notification Generator*** provided by Roman Nurik on https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html

In that way, you can use an image (taking into consideration that this has to have transparent background) and let the generator do the job for you generating the different sizes for notification icons.

The most important thing is that if the icon generator after you browse the image you are going to use shows you a white filled circle or square, there are problems with your image, maybe because it doesn't have any transparencies, so make sure that you has this ok.

Comment: In my case, I had vector in `drawable` folder and png's in `drawable-hdpi`, `xhdpi`, etc. But there was no png for `drawable-mdpi`, and it crashed on MDPI device on posting a notification.

Answer (score 11):

**android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted**

I had the same issue, but I was resolved. My problem is ".xml file" of Remote view.

In my xml file I was added one `View` in between the `LinearLayout` for divider.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:background="#000000" />
```

The above `View` component creating the Bad notification exception. This Exception reason is only xml file of Remoteviews.

After removing that View component, My code executed properly, without any exception. So I felt that Notification drawer not accepting any customized views.

So you don't draw any thing like the above view in the .xml file of `RemoteView` object.

Comment: Meaning `View` is not supported?

Answer (score 9):

In my app, this kind of bug happens only during upgrading. If the resource id changes in the newer version, Android `RemoteView` may fail to find the resource and throw out the `RemoteServiceException`. If you publish a 3rd version and do not change the resource id, the bugs may disappear **only temporarily**.

It is possible to reduce this kind of bugs by editing `res/values/public.xml` and `res/values/ids.xml`. Compiler will generate an individual resource id if the resource id is not in `public.xml` or `ids.xml`. When u change the resource name or add some new resources, the id may change and some devices may fail to find it.

So the step is as following:

1. Decompile the apk file and in `res/values` find the `public.xml` and `ids.xml`
2. Find all resources related to RemoteView in your app and copy them ( strings, dimen, drawable, layout, id, color... )
3. Create `public.xml` and `ids.xml` under `res/values` in your source code and paste the lines u just copied

Note:

Gradle 1.3.0 and above ignore the local `public.xml`. To make it work, u need to add some script in your `build.gradle`

```
afterEvaluate {
    for (variant in android.applicationVariants) {
        def scope = variant.getVariantData().getScope()
        String mergeTaskName = scope.getMergeResourcesTask().name
        def mergeTask = tasks.getByName(mergeTaskName)
        mergeTask.doLast {
            copy {
                int i=0
                from(android.sourceSets.main.res.srcDirs) {
                    include 'values/public.xml'
                    rename 'public.xml', (i == 0? "public.xml": "public_${i}.xml")
                    i++
                }
                into(mergeTask.outputDir)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note:
This script does not support submodules project. I am trying to fix it.

Answer (score 6):

In Android Studio version 3.0.0 and above, when adding a new image in the drawables folder choose drawable instead of drawable-v24.[image]

If the image,you are using, is alread a (v24) just copy it and paste it in its same directory (eg. drawables). This time it will ask you which regular or v24 - just make sure its not the v24 and try it again this should fix the error.

Comment: Notice - if you are in "Android" view, switch it to "Project" view.

In Android view, you may not see the drawables v24 directory

Comment: I think this works fine for me. You can put that vector xml file in both drawable and drawable v24. Those android version less than or equal to Marsha mellow will pick it up from drawable folder, and the newer version will pick it up from drawable v24.

Comment: Yes it happened in my case, my mipmap was only for v26

Answer (score 5):

Just in case the icon is not important, you can replace,

```
R.drawable.your_icon
```

To

```
android.R.drawable.some_standard_icon
```

This works!

Comment: So you are going to compromise with your custom/own icons :)

Answer (score 5):

If you have a notification visible while your app is updated, you might run into this. What you may need to do is create a BroadcastReceiver that waits for a PACKAGE_CHANGED message, at which point you shutdown all your services which will also dismiss their associated notifications.

```
 <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 4):

I had RemoteServiceException when use Notification in my class extends from FirebaseMessagingService. I added the following code to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
android:resource="@drawable/ic_small" />
```

**Also** resource ic_small set in instance of a class Notification.Builder by method setSmallIcon(int icon).

Comment: this metadata has to be added inside the <service </service> tags?

Answer (score 3):

You have pass same icon

```
     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_name" />
```

and you notification

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                        .setContentTitle("Title")
                        .setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: I've passed vector image as a resource and I think it caused the crashes on oneplus/android 6 devices. Not sure for 100%.

Answer (score 3):

Same issue happened with me as well and I have solved the same

**REASON**: This is happening because of we are using vector drawable for RemoteViews and vector drawable generates drawable at compile-time. Also I am not sure why some devices are not able to detect the generated drawable resources id while we are upping the app. But yes this was the reason.

**REPRODUCE**
Steps
 1. Install previous build.
 2. Send a notification
 3. Update the build with next version code
 4. After updating the app don't open the app and send notification again

**SOLUTION**
Replace the vector drawable with normal drawable(.png or .jpg) file.

I hope this resolves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

(this is not solution for current question but helps someone with similar core issue) I too had the same issue, But in my case I have used corrupted .png file which is causing same issue. So I have deleted it and re-included correct .png file.

Answer (score 1):

You can put that vector xml file in both drawable and drawable v24. Those android version less than or equal to Android 6 will pick it up from drawable folder, and and newer version above android 6 will pick it up from drawable v24.

Answer (score 1):

> Its not about the Image type (vector, png, etc.) but the folder to which you are referring
> to.

For me the error caused was due to a device (Nougat) referring to an icon present in v26 folder.

Solution: Just add the relevant icon to the other folder as well and the issue will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I set a notification in a bundle.
I tried this and it solved my problem:

```
builder.setLargeIcon(large_icon);
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_icon);
```

Make sure that setLargeIcon() invoked before setSmallIcon().

Comment: Why should this help?

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue. The issue is with the icon which you are using, I was using android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download. Go to drawables.xml and paste this.

```
<resources>
 <item name="ic_start_download" type="drawable">@android:drawable/stat_sys_download</item>
</resource>
```

and then in your code

```
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_start_download);
```

You can try some other image instead of this image

Answer (score 0):

My way to solve this: I had "bad" views in my layout (ex: a checkbox) - so I removed them.

RemoteViews seem to support only images and texts (to be confirmed by reading the doc).

Answer (score 0):

I had RemoteServiceException when use android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout. Change it to LinearLayout or Relative
and also android:layout_height="wrap_content" for container

Answer (score 0):

Please replace `<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView` with **`<TextView`** from custom notification layout.

Because `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView` or `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView` only works at runtime.

So Use **`TextView`** or **`ImageView`**

Answer (score 0):

If any one still facing this issue :
Add a png file in your drawable folder with name ic_stat_ic_notification    (or any name u like )

and in your manifest add below couple of lines

and u can create your icons over here - >
https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icon

Answer (score 0):

I got this error due to autolink and linksClickable options in textview in notification view:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:autoLink="all"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Be careful!

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem of icon location. In my case the notification icon was in drawable-anydpi-v24, I simply copied the icon in drawable folder and the error has gone.

Answer (score 0):

Got this error in my Flutter android app and checked to see that all the resources are present and named correctly but still not working, I was using resources from mipmap. I changed it to drawable and placed the notification icons inside drawble folders and fixed the issue, hoping it might help someone later on

Answer (score -1):

Synchrinize the project and than Clean it, 
File > Synchronize then : Build > Clean Project

I hope that will help you all, It's work for me

Answer (score -3):

This **worked** for me. Comment the reference of the icon and thus be able to use the NotificationCompat.Builder without problems.

```
    $msg_notificacion = [
                        'title'         => "titulonotif",
                       // "icon" : "myicon",
                        'body'          =>"cuerponotif"
                    ];
```