# Android 5 Bad notification posted from package

Tags: android, notifications

i got a lot of exceptions with the following stacktrace.
For Android < 5.0 it works fine.

I get the errors from my LED notification app LED Blinker.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ledblinker
I post a notification without an icon. I dont know how to reproduce it, but i got a lot of crash reports.

Any suggestions?

```
ANDROID_VERSION=5.0
PHONE_MODEL=Nexus 5
BUILD=BOARD=hammerhead
BOOTLOADER=HHZ12d
BRAND=google
CPU_ABI=armeabi-v7a
CPU_ABI2=armeabi
DEVICE=hammerhead
DISPLAY=LRX21O
FINGERPRINT=google/hammerhead/hammerhead:5.0/LRX21O/1570415:user/release-keys
HARDWARE=hammerhead
ID=LRX21O
MANUFACTURER=LGE
MODEL=Nexus 5
PRODUCT=hammerhead
RADIO=unknown
SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS=[Ljava.lang.String;@2b1c12b
SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS=[Ljava.lang.String;@20cc8988
SUPPORTED_ABIS=[Ljava.lang.String;@302e2f21
TAGS=release-keys
TYPE=user
UNKNOWN=unknown
USER=android-build
IS_DEBUGGABLE=false
TIME=1415320210000
VERSION.ACTIVE_CODENAMES=[Ljava.lang.String;@2a8c4f46
VERSION.CODENAME=REL
VERSION.INCREMENTAL=1570415
VERSION.RELEASE=5.0
VERSION.SDK=21
VERSION.RESOURCES_SDK_INT=21
VERSION.SDK_INT=21

USER_APP_START_DATE=2014-12-08T05:50:24.000+01:00
USER_CRASH_DATE=2014-12-08T07:32:05.000+01:00
CUSTOM_DATA=
STACK_TRACE=android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package com.ledblinker: Couldn't create icon: StatusBarIcon(pkg=com.ledblinkeruser=0 id=0x0 level=0 visible=true num=0 )
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1441)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Everything is working, but sometimes this error occurs.

Here is the code that is causing it:

```
Notification resetNoti = new Notification(); 
resetNoti.ledARGB = Color.RED; 
resetNoti.ledOffMS = 0; 
resetNoti.ledOnMS = 1; 
resetNoti.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
```

Comment: No suggestions what i can do?

Comment: This happened to me, too, yesterday, for the first time ever. On a Nexus 5 with Android 5.0. Weird! But not from your app, which is not installed. Reading the dump, I cannot work out to which app it refers.

Comment: Yes i think its once again a firmware bug. I use this code since 2 years now and it never happed since 5.0.

Comment: can you post the code which posts the notification. I see that the id is 0, which is the id of the Status bar icon drawable that needs to be shown.

Comment: Notification resetNoti = new Notification();
resetNoti.ledARGB = Color.RED;
resetNoti.ledOffMS = 0;
resetNoti.ledOnMS = 1;
resetNoti.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

Comment: Got this on a device running 4.4.2 (sdk 19).
Related to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317659/how-to-fix-android-app-remoteserviceexception-bad-notification-posted-from-pac

Comment: I have user reports with the same issue on Android 4.4

Comment: @MOST2K2, did you able to figure out this, I am still getting this in Android 6

Answer (score 1):

Try using NotificationCompat.Builder class to create notification. It allows for the new notification design (including big-text for expandable notifications) with support for older notification style.
You can then set notification color using setLights. Also you need an object of Notification which you can get from the builder object using getNotification().

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notify = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
notify.setLights(Color.argb(255, 255, 0, 0), 5000, 5000);
notify.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_kw);
notify.setContentTitle("Title");
notify.setContentText("Text");

Intent showIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, showIntent, 0); 
notify.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(0, notify.getNotification());
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: I get the same bug as the one from the question, but I am already using NotificationCompat.Builder, it does not fix the problem.

Comment: @YoannHercouet, have you got any solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

It is icon issue, lollipop doesn't support XML icon or vector inside notification. You have to use PNG icon for notification.

Another issue could be icon resource file mismatch, if in the manifest file meta-data contains any information about push notification icon then it must be the same file used in notification builder `setSmallIcon()`.