# Bad notification posted on android 7

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I got an app on play store with this below crash, but I don't know how can I fix. The crash only happens on Android 7.

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package br.com.apname: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(pkg=br.com.apname user=UserHandle{0} id=1370050766 tag=null key=0|br.com.apname|1370050766|null|10133: Notification(pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x10 color=0xff2196f3 actions=1 vis=PUBLIC))
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1644)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Comment: Try reading [How to fix: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package \*: Couldn't create icon: StatusBarIcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317659/how-to-fix-android-app-remoteserviceexception-bad-notification-posted-from-pac)

Comment: This is not the same crash. But thank you. In my case it`s about RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification.

Comment: Are you sure that all views in content view of the notification are valid remote views?

Comment: can you please post your code where you code for notification as well please.

Comment: You r u using vector icons in ur notifications?

Comment: Please share the code for your remoteview.

Comment: post your code and your xml. i assume you're trying to put a view of a kind that RemoteView doesn't allow(for example : EditText)

Comment: All we can do is assume things as OP is not responding answers. Question should be closed so as not anyone stumble on this when trying to find a solution.

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue. But the issue is not reproducible. I am getting these crash logs via Fabric. As for people asking to post the code, I am sure that there is no problem in the code as it is working for most of the users. Only some users on Android 7 are facing this issue.