# Getting a error with Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm just starting with `Firebase` and I was trying with a kind of complex code that I saw on a tutorial, and I get an error, so I just copied a simple code,  very basic, but I'm still getting the same error, please help me, I'm gonna put the `FirebaseInstanceIdService` and the `FirebaseMessagingService`, but if you need further information please let me know.

**The error that I'm getting**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.bim.tech.construbimapp, PID: 30988
 android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package com.bim.tech.construbimapp: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.bim.tech.construbimapp user=UserHandle{0} id=0 tag=FCM-Notification:250274573 score=0 key=0|com.bim.tech.construbimapp|0|FCM-Notification:250274573|10184: Notification(pri=0 contentView=com.bim.tech.construbimapp/0x1090077 vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x10 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE))
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1638)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

**FirebaseMessagingService**

```
public class MiFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

public static final String TAG = "SERVICIOS";


@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    String from = remoteMessage.getFrom();
    Log.d(TAG, "Mensaje recibido de " + from);

    if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null){
        Log.d(TAG, "Notificacion" + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        mostrarNotificacion(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0 ){
        Log.d(TAG, "Data: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

}

private void mostrarNotificacion(String title, String body) {

    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity_Metodos_de_Pago.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.builder)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

**FirebaseInstanceIdService**

```
public class MiFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    super.onTokenRefresh();

    String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    Log.d(TAG, "Token: " + token);

    enviarTokenAlServidor(token);
}
private void enviarTokenAlServidor(String token) {
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package \*: Couldn't create icon: StatusBarIcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317659/how-to-fix-android-app-remoteserviceexception-bad-notification-posted-from-pac)

Comment: This should fix it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39206859/4026792