# How do I fix this exception - looks caused by firebase messaging?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

A user on a Samsung phone (model SM-G950F) and running Android 7.0 is causing a load of these exceptions in Firebase messaging.

Am I right in thinking I can't do anything about them ?

- My app is not inflating a custom layout.
- We're using firebase 11.0.4

Exception android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package com.my.app: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.my.app user=UserHandle{0} id=0 tag=FCM-Notification:1074471639 key=0|com.my.app|0|FCM-Notification:1074471639|10212: Notification(pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=content://settings/system/notification_sound defaults=0x0 flags=0x10 color=0xff3f51b5 vis=PRIVATE semFlags=0x0 semPriority=0))

```
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1813)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

EDIT:
this is not a dupe of [How to fix: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package *: Couldn't create icon: StatusBarIcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317659/how-to-fix-android-app-remoteserviceexception-bad-notification-posted-from-pac)

That particular question has a completely different title; `Couldn't create icon` versus `Couldn't expand RemoteViews`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package \*: Couldn't create icon: StatusBarIcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317659/how-to-fix-android-app-remoteserviceexception-bad-notification-posted-from-pac)

Comment: not a dupe - please see edit