# Google Play Console crash report not related to my app

Tags: android, crash-reports, google-play-console

Google Play Console reported crashes for an app of mine that obviously do not relate to my app. This information is provided:

> android.app.RemoteServiceException:
>
> 1. at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1768)
> 2. at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
> 3. at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
> 4. at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6494)
> 5. at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
> 6. at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:438)
> 7. at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:807)

As you can see my app is not even mentioned. So I wonder whether that crash report actually relates to my app. Resp. I'd like to know how to identify the issue in my coding causing that crash. Maybe the stack trace is truncated. But I cannot access any subsequent items.

Any ideas appreciated.

This is not the same as the question mentioned. There it is about fixing a concrete issue. Here it is about a vague issue indicated by Google Play Console, not being specific whether or how that issue relates to my app at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package \*: Couldn't create icon: StatusBarIcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317659/how-to-fix-android-app-remoteserviceexception-bad-notification-posted-from-pac)

Answer (score 0):

It will always relate to your app - Google Play knows for the crash which process it belongs to, and each app has it's own process. If you don't see your app mentioned, it will be because your code inherits from some other code in the Android Platform. In the example you give above, the crash will be happening in an ActivityThread for an activity in your app.

Android is open source. So you can look at the source code and see what might be happening.

Searching in Google for "ActivityThread source code" finds [the source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java).

Looking at line 1768 you see the RemoteServiceException is thrown because a [SCHEDULE_CRASH message was received](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java#1768).

Searching the android source code will help you see what might have caused this.

Comment: And how is that helpful? The cause of the `SCHEDULE_CRASH` message remains unknown. Needless to say, many manufacturers tweak the Android source code as they see fit, making research for bugs from stack traces like these pointless.