# Android version 7.0 or above create exception android.app.RemoteServiceException:

Tags: android-studio-3.0, android-7.0-nougat, remoteexception

Android version 7.0 or above create exception when we upload an update of my app crashes will be given

> android.app.RemoteServiceException:    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1681) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:241)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6274)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
>   (ZygoteInit.java:886)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
>   (ZygoteInit.java:776)

[image: Google Play Developer Console reports this crashes]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package \*: Couldn't create icon: StatusBarIcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317659/how-to-fix-android-app-remoteserviceexception-bad-notification-posted-from-pac)

Comment: Hey @Ahmad, Is this really duplicate what Graham posted? I am facing the same issue and don't have anything like "Bad notification..." in the stack trace. Did you able to fix the issue?

Comment: @FuatCoşkun its not duplicate the Exception is same but the issue is different.. yet I completely not understand the actual problem because crash trace not properly define where the problem exist

Comment: @AhmadJoyia getting the same issue, please provide any help

Comment: The same report here totally has no idea what's wrong.