# setSmallIcon crashes on Android 4.4

Tags: android, notifications

I have next crash on android 4.4

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException
Bad notification posted from package myapp: 
Couldn't create icon: StatusBarIcon(pkg=myappr=0 id=0x7f080117 level=0 visible=true num=0 )
```

I realized that the problem is in the setsmallIcon method. People write that before API 21 you need to use PNG, and then you can use vector. okay, I do.

Here's how I do

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder 
= new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext(), REMINDER_CHANNEL_ID)            
.setSmallIcon(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP ? R.drawable.ic_notification : R.mipmap.ic_notification)
```

`drawable.ic_notification` is `xml`, `mipmap.ic`_notification is png for `mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi.`
Tell me, please, how to deal with this problem? I read a lot of topics, but the distinct answer have not received. Thanks

Comment: have you checked this question it relates to your exception :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317659/how-to-fix-android-app-remoteserviceexception-bad-notification-posted-from-pac

Comment: change your icon and try it. some icon type not supported

Comment: @Umair i read it, but don't help me

Comment: @HemalHerath you can learn more about what is not supported

Comment: @Nikitc try changing the name of either notification icon or png image's. and then clean your project and re-run it.

Comment: @Umair I can't replicate this behavior. everything works fine for me. but judging by crashlytics many users on android 4 have such a problem.

Comment: @Nikitc does useSupportLibrary is set to true in your gradle file ?

Comment: @Umair does'nt. I need set true?

Comment: @Nikitc try setting this in your .gradle file
        
       vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true