Bad notification(tag=null, id=100) posted from package : Crash on App launch after app update
I have an app on play store, whenever users are updating app and upon first launch the app is getting crashed multiple times with below logs reported on firebase crashlytics:
Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException$BadForegroundServiceNotificationException: Bad notification(tag=null, id=100) posted from package com.xx.xx.xx, crashing app(uid=10266, pid=29430): Couldn't inflate contentViewsandroid.widget.RemoteViews$ActionException: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13 in com.xx.xx.xx:layout/permission_popup: Binary XML file line #13 in com.xx.xx.xx:layout/permission_popup: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
       at android.app.ActivityThread.throwRemoteServiceException(ActivityThread.java:2225)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mthrowRemoteServiceException()
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2508)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8762)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)

The layout mentioned in the crash logs is not being used for notification but somehow it comes over there, with every app update the crash shows different layout.
I have a different layout for notification which I am using through remoteviews.
This crash started mainly happening on Android 13 onwards.

First answer in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317659/how-to-fix-android-app-remoteserviceexception-bad-notification-posted-from-pac might be helpful for you.
