# Flutter notifications not working on android devices

Tags: dart, flutter

I've been following this guide to try out notifications, https://medium.com/@nitishk72/flutter-local-notification-1e43a353877b, and the main API documentation for the flutter local notification package but I keep getting various errors, on a modern phone it vibrates only and no notification pops up, on an older device (emulator), i get this error `android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package com.xxx: Couldn't create icon: StatusBarIcon(icon=Icon(typ=RESOURCE pkg=com.xxx id=0x7f040000) visible user=0 )` can anyone help?

I wasn't able to test on an iOS device

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix this bug : "android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24968556/how-to-fix-this-bug-android-app-remoteserviceexception-bad-notification-post)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve using a notification service as alternative. I really recommend [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com). It is a Notifications Service that works on multiple platforms and recently they added Flutter support to OneSignal.

There is SDK Documentation pages for Flutter:

- [Setup Guide for Flutter Project](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/flutter-sdk-setup)
- [OneSignal for Flutter SDK Docs](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/flutter-sdk)